# how to insert into table Int And Textbox=varchar And Richtextbox=(varcharMax) Types

Tags: c#, .net

I have been trying to insert values of user input into my sql DB but it failed a bunch of times. Here are different ways that I have tried:

```
private void VessDet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into Ves (Imo , VEsName , First_Bay, Last_Bay , TL_Condition ) values ( " + txtImo.Text + ",'" + txtName.Text + "'," + txtFirstBay.Text + "," + txtLastBay.Text +",'" + richTextBox1.Text + "' ) ", cnx);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into Ves (Imo,VEsName,First_Bay,Last_Bay,TL_Condition) values ( @Imo,@VEsName,@First_Bay,@Last_Bay,@TL_Condition ) ", cnx);
      cnx.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Imo", txtImo.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@VEsName", txtImo.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@First_Bay", txtImo.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last_Bay", txtImo.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@TL_Condition", txtImo.Text);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         cnx.Close();
}
```

and Here is the 2nd way i tried

```
private void VessDet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into Ves (Imo , VEsName , First_Bay, Last_Bay , TL_Condition ) values ( " + txtImo.Text + ",'" + txtName.Text + "'," + txtFirstBay.Text + "," + txtLastBay.Text +",'" + richTextBox1.Text + "' ) ", cnx);

      string ab = ("insert into Ves (Imo , VEsName , First_Bay, Last_Bay , TL_Condition ) Values ('" + txtImo.Text+"','"+txtName.Text+ "' ,"+txtFirstBay.Text+" ,"+txtLastBay.Text +" ,'"+richTextBox1.Text.ToString()+"' )");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ab, cnx);
      cnx.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnx.Close();

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no im not getting an error exept that when i go to check in my DB if its been Added i find them all empty ,exept for first bay and last bay that have 0 value in them, for the record i show you type of columns on table {VesID is PK} {IMO is Varchar but input will be 8 numbers } {VesName is varchar(MAX) and input will be string} {First bay will only be 1 or 2 and its Int} {LAST bay is int and input is int} {TL-condition is varchar(MAX) and input will be long text }

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to make sure your connection string is initialized.

Side note: Looks like you may be copy/pasting txtImo.Text instead of using the correct textbox for each.

Update:

Try casting your text field to an integer.  I believe the syntax is:
(int)txtbox.Text

Update 2:

Try adding your parameter with the db type explicitly stated:
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Imo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int.Parse(txtImo.Text);

BTW, Int.Parse is the correct way to convert to int here.

Comment: thanks for th response guys, but i kinda checked that im selecting the right exact Texboxes and still input doesnt get inserted
Edited : i changed the paste of txtImo.Text 
it was a mistake but still no data inserted in DB

Comment: it gave me that its impossible to convert string to int , this is driving me crazy i tried convert.toint aswell but still nothing , your answer are much appreciated .

Comment: i feel like it was a good attempt but still nothing and thnks for the information about th int.parse even tho the error seems like its there while clicking on the add button it just gave back that the format of that int.parse is incorrect

Comment: just for clarifiation IMO IS VARCHAR(MAX) while the input is a group of a unique number 8888888 like this . i didnt specify it as constraint unique in sql for some reasons , could the problem be arround that? and also First_Bay is INT while in the input is int as well and Last_Bay is exactly like First_Bay

Comment: sorry for too many comments but just to inform you guys that for example when i insert data in the query directly it does go through 
insert into Ves (Imo , VEsName , First_Bay, Last_Bay , TL_Condition ) Values ('285698','Cieslo','2','22','long text should be stored here')
please if someone have a point to propose I even turned JUST NOW the Last_Bay  and First_Bay  COLUMNS to Varchar

Comment: Do you get values when you print the Int.Parse of your integer-expecting text boxes to a message box?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are trying send string value to integer parameter.

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Imo", txtImo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@VEsName", txtImo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@First_Bay", int.Parse(txtImo.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last_Bay", int.Parse(txtImo.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TL_Condition", txtImo.Text);
```

Comment: thanks sir for the reply but i actually tried the int.parse in second methode , as i tried it now but it gave me that the syntax is incorrect 
The format of the input string is incorrect. '
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@First_Bay", int.Parse(txtFirstBay.Text));
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Last_Bay", int.Parse(txtLastBay.Text));

Answer (score 0):

Hello again guys this was originally my post , i actually had to eat , anyway i found where was the problem , if you go back to the code you will robably notice that im trying to insert into... in a LOAD_form , all i did was actually switch to the button code and type that code thanks everyone for your help , you are the best

---

> ***private void VessDet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {***

---

this where code should have been put

> private void BNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {